# Why does apt-cache list also packages which are NOT installed?

Tags: apt

For example:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache pkgnames | less | sort > inst_pkgs.txt
```

Output

```
....
virtualbox
virtualbox-4.3
virtualbox-5.0
virtualbox-dbg
virtualbox-dkms
virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
virtualbox-guest-dkms
virtualbox-guest-source
virtualbox-guest-utils
virtualbox-guest-x11
virtualbox-nonfree
virtualbox-qt
virtualbox-source
....
```

but when I try

> sudo apt-get remove virtualbox # or any other of the packages above

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 252 not upgraded.
```

Comment: because it's meant to show you available pakage in your repositories ,          
when you run ` apt-get update ` you get the list of all pakeges to be disponible for `apt-cache`

Comment: https://www.debian.org/doc//manuals/debian-handbook/sect.apt-get.en.html

Answer (score 2):

`apt-cache` is for interacting with the apt cache that's built or updated with `apt-get update`.  This has nothing to do with what is currently installed on your system.

Simply put, `apt-get` is used for modifying available packages while `apt-cache` is used for querying them.

From the help text:

> `apt-get` is a simple command line interface for downloading and
>   installing packages.

<sup>*[Linux man page - apt-get(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)*</sup>

---

> `apt-cache` is a low-level tool used to query information from APT's
>   binary cache files

<sup>*[Linux man page - apt-cache(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-cache)*</sup>

Comment: `apt-cache` can be used to search a program to install. Imagine you want to install a software that support `pgn` files, then `apt-cache search pgn` will show you what is available.